# how to make my ldap client as sudo user in mac

Tags: macos, ldap, sudoers

I loged in as ldap client against ldap server authentication. when i open terminal and enter sudo -i, i get an error message that this user is not added in sudoers file. what to do get root permissions.

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/adding-ad-domain-groups-to-etcsudoers/ - it takes you through editing the `/etc/sudoers` file to add an Active Directory group to be able to `sudo` whenever they are logged in.

Comment: Thank you @Big Chris, but we are using LDAPV3 not Active directory as our LDAP server is Linux,not windows